# Invoke-RestMethod : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the invoke-resthmethod to call a set of REST API's but it always fails with the below error

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:1 char:4
+ $a=Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -uri $urlsend -Headers $header -Bod ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Tried both the options below

Option 1 : -->

```
 ################################################
# Adding certificate exception to prevent API errors
################################################
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
```

Option 2 : -->

```
  [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

But still it results in the below error

[image]

Windows Server version - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard edition

Comment: What does the error log of the webserver say? Is TLS even enabled?

Comment: root@vra-01a [ ~ ]# openssl ciphers -v | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq
SSLv3
TLSv1.2

Comment: yes SSLv3 and TLSv1.2 are enabled

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Webserver i was trying to connect to does not have the supported ciphers which are present in windows 2012 r2, post an upgrade to windows 2016 it got fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Upgrade to windows 2016 was not enough in my case. After the upgrade i run Version "3.0.1, SetupIISForSSLPerfectForwardSecrecy.ps1" from hass.de site it got fixed

Comment: Use the comment section for a couple of lines answer.